# Drawer View in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

this is my first mac application, and i have been wanting to make something like this:

[image]

But, i have been looking and have found nearly nothing about the Window and Drawer. How can i put this into my application? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a drawer, that's a [sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TPXREF11). Here's the [conceptual documentation about sheets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000002i), which includes sample code.

Comment: Ok, i feel embarrassed, i am sorry, also, could you post some code on how i would add one to my project, and activate it? Thanks

Comment: If you click the 2nd link, there is all sorts of example code.

Comment: Thanks, also, could you come to chat please, to help me with some dataBinding issues i am having? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23818/elite-gamer-and-kurt